# How to make routing for search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I use searchkick for searching.
Form search will be in path `/products`. After submitting the search, I want to see the results in the path, something like this:

```
"?utf8=✓&search%5Bmeta_sort%5D=orders_count.desc&search%5Bt"
```

How do i build a form which will submit these parameters?

Comment: Can you expand on your question please?  "What should i do?" is too vague.  Explain your requirements, and someone can help you meet them.  For example do you mean "How do i build a form which will submit these parameters?" ?  Or something else?

Comment: okey, i edited my question)

Comment: If i call `URI.unescape` on your param string i get `"?utf8=✓&search[meta_sort]=orders_count.desc&search[t"`.  This isn't a legal params string: note the "open square bracket" near the end without a close bracket.  It looks like it's been truncated, ie that it was supposed to be something like  `"?utf8=✓&search[meta_sort]=orders_count.desc&search[term]=foo"`.  Is that the case?